# Most elegant pipe to get rid of empty lines you can think of?

Tags: text-processing

For e. g., `less` has option `--squeeze-blank-lines` (or `-s` in short) and it squeezes multiple blank lines into *single* blank line, buuut, `less` wouldn't do this being used as filter (i. e., having its output sent not to a tty).

Similar option can be found in `cat` too, it's also called `-s` usually, and it also makes single blank line instead of several.

What about removing empty/blank lines all together? One approach I can think of is using `grep`, but may be I've overlooked something more simple?

Comment: Depends, how were you thinking of using `grep`?

Comment: my go to command is `grep -v ^$ filename`

Comment: @MelBurslan why not just `grep . filename`? Or, to also remove non-empty lines with whitespace: `grep -E '\S' filename`

Comment: The title of this question asks about empty lines (but the body says "empty/blank"), whereas the target question title clearly says blank (i.e. whitespace-only) lines. Let's all please take care not to have titles mismatching the body.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `awk`!

```
echo -e "dada

ada

bada

" | awk NF
```

results in

```
dada
ada
bada
```

Comment: This post explains how `awk NF` works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544804/how-awk-nf-filename-is-working